# Table is bad for layout, but what's about CSS table-cell

Tags: html, css, layout

We all now using table for layout is bad thing. But what's about using table-cell? E.g. i need two blocks one is 200px width and other is 100% - 200px (ye, i know about float hack and also about CSS3 calc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, but I don't think there's any problem with it.

The table is discouraged for design because it should hold tabular data - it's semantically wrong to put eg. menu and article in table cells.

Comment: But what is not the hack? The only non-hack solution is flexbox, but for now it's not usable.

Comment: You didn't read the question. The OP is specifically not referring to HTML tables. Semantics aren't really relevant here.

Comment: That's a lie, the OP mentioned table for layout as a bad thing. I explained why it is bad and why table-cell display is ok.

Answer (score 1):

While you are right with the notion that using tables for layouts bad... that mostly stems from that additional unnecessary markup. `td` and `tr` elements do not provide the correct semantically meaning for what you want.

With that said, there is nothing wrong with applying `display: table-cell;` on divs, its just another way of structuring layout.

(In fact, `table-cell` provides one of the few ways to vertically center a div with variable height).

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is for display of a table and table cell. The idea about using tables for layout causes issues with the structure of the page. The CSS property does not affect structure hence there is no issue with using that for visual layout.